# Regex issue with special char

Tags: javascript, regex

I using this regular expression :

`let regex = /([a-z])|([A-Z])|([0-9])|([$!@.-])/gu;`

To have in 4 four groups (upper case), (upper case),(number), (a special char).

For have this four groups I use a loop where the groups is $+i until five:

`arrayGroup.push(valueToCompare.replace(stringRegex, "$" + i));`

My issue is the following :

> When I use #{[|`\^@] (all special char) for instance, there match in the four groups. I don't understand why?

Example with this string :

`let string = "groupGROUP123@!-"`

`$1 = group`
`$2 = GROUP`
`$3 = 123`
`$4 = @!-`

It's ok here. Now whith others special char not specified into the regular expression

`let string = "groupGROUP123@!#{[{[@^~]-"`

`$1 = group#{[{[@^~]`
`$2 = GROUP#{[{[@^~]`
`$3 = 123#{[{[@^~]`
`$4 = @!-#{[{[@^~]`

That my issue

Comment: Can you please  build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to explain more precisely what result you expected?

Comment: @DenysSéguret Ok I do thanks

Comment: What is expected result for `let string = "groupGROUP123@!#{[{[@^~]-"` string?

Comment: Please add details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you match all groups regardless where there are.

Regular expression should be like this, e.g.

`([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)([$!@.-]+)`